# update StateProvider with flutter_riverpod

Tags: flutter, hook, provider, flutter-riverpod, session-state-provider

Is it possible to update `StateProvider` from the Class outside the Widget?

Or I need to use another way?

**My code**

```
class SettingScreen extends ConsumerWidget with WidgetsBindingObserver {
```

This is the place I would like to update the state

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
     Update and read state working fine 
    }
}
var locationPermissionProvider = StateProvider<bool>((_) => true,);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution and it's working

- removed `WidgetRef` & `StateProvider`
- changed to `StatefulWidget`
- update the state inside `setState`
- and change the state in the following function inside the class

  ```
  didChangeAppLifecycleState
  ```